# XPath that selects a second element if the first element is blank

Tags: xml, if-statement, xpath, nodes

I have some XML that sometimes looks like this:

```
<object>
    <item>
        <name>Item Name</name>
    </item>
 </object>
```

And then can sometimes lack the Name element and have another name:

```
<object>
    <item>
        <name/>
        <altname>Item Name 2</altname>
    </item>
 </object>
```

The logic behind what I need is:

If  has a value, use that. If it doesn't, use .

I tried adapting what I found here:

[XPath: Default to 'Node A', select 'Node B' instead if 'Node B' is not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370362/xpath-default-to-node-a-select-node-b-instead-if-node-b-is-not-empty)

But to no avail... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With XPath-2.0 and above you can do this with

```
if (item/name !='') then item/name else item/altname
```

With XPath-1.0 only it's a bit more tricky, but this will work:

```
item/name[. !=''] | item/altname[../name ='']
```

Comment: The XPath 1.0 answer worked perfectly for me, thanks!